# Web Api and dependency injection with StructureMap using http scoped instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, ravendb, structuremap

As the title says, I'm trying to use dependency injection using StructureMap, Web Api and `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` instance of a RavenDB session.

For that I'm using a `IHttpControllerActivator`, see code below.

```
public class StructureMapControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public StructureMapControllerActivator(IContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        try
        {
            var scopedContainer = _container.GetNestedContainer();
            scopedContainer.Inject(typeof(HttpRequestMessage), request);
            request.RegisterForDispose(scopedContainer);
            return (IHttpController)scopedContainer.GetInstance(controllerType);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO : Logging
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

In my global.asax I wire up the `IHttpControllerActivator` like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new StructureMapControllerActivator(ApplicationContainer));
```

And this is my configuration for StructureMap:

```
expression.For<IDocumentStore>().Use(documentStore);
expression.For<IDocumentSession>()
    .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
    .Use(container =>
    {
        var store = container.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>();                        
        return store.OpenSession();
    });
```

In my `ApiController` I have a constructor like this:

```
public MyApiController(IDocumentSession session) {
    _session = session;
}
```

When I make the first `Request` I get an instance of the `DocumentSession`, but the second `Request` throws an `HttpError` exception on this line `return store.OpenSession()`. The exception states that the object is already disposed and cannot be used. This is the complete exception:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "StructureMap Exception Code:  207\nInternal exception while creating Instance '6d9a72a3-3044-495a-909c-dd9fe7527c80' of PluginType Raven.Client.IDocumentSession, Raven.Client.Lightweight, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593.  Check the inner exception for more details.",
  "exceptionType": "StructureMap.StructureMapException",
  "stackTrace": "   at BrickPile.Mvc.StructureMapControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) in c:\\Users\\maqe\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\brickpile\\BrickPile\\Mvc\\StructureMapWebApiDependencyResolver.cs:line 61\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()",
  "innerException": {
    "$type": "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "The document store has already been disposed and cannot be used\r\nObject name: 'EmbeddableDocumentStore'.",
    "exceptionType": "System.ObjectDisposedException",
    "stackTrace": "   at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.OpenSession(OpenSessionOptions options) in c:\\Builds\\RavenDB-Stable\\Raven.Client.Lightweight\\Document\\DocumentStore.cs:line 355\r\n   at BrickPile.DefaultBrickPileBootstrapper.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ConfigureApplicationContainerInternal>b__a(IContext container) in c:\\Users\\maqe\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\brickpile\\BrickPile\\DefaultBrickPileBootstrapper.cs:line 294\r\n   at StructureMap.Pipeline.LambdaInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session) in c:\\BuildAgent\\work\\767273992e840853\\src\\StructureMap\\Pipeline\\LambdaInstance.cs:line 25"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with what I am missing here?

I forgot to mention that I use an `IHttpModule` for releasing and disposing all http scoped objects in `Application_EndRequest`.

Comment: I added `.Singleton()` to `expression.For<IDocumentStore>().Use(documentStore);` and now it seems to work with the exact same code I posted in my question. Can anyone confirm the solution?

Comment: That is correct. The `IDocumentStore` instance should be a singleton and the `IDocumentSession` instance should be HTTP scoped. By default StructureMap creates a new instance of the class every time.

Comment: Sure you want to `throw e;`? Most every time, it should just be `throw;` as you're losing your call stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had forgotten to add `.Singleton()` to `expression.For<IDocumentStore>().Use(documentStore);`. The code above works as expected with this modification.